# How to send a keystroke to a x11 vnc session (xtightvncviewer)

Tags: bash, x11, vnc

I need to press a ceratin Key after setting up a server connection via xtightvncviewer in order to make an automated screenshot. Can i pass it with the startupscript?

~/VNC# xtightvncviewer  myserver.dyndns.org -bgr233 -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd

Answer (score 1):

You can open xtightvncviewer on a different display, then use scrot to take a screenshot.

There are of course methods to send keystrokes too, which is what you asked for, but it seems to be an uglier solution (if you ask me). For example check out these links:

- http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html
- http://packages.debian.org/lenny/xdotool

Comment: Is there any way to send a keystroke/mousemove to VNC directly? The protocol obviously does this, so sending the appropriate data to the appropriate port should do this? This seems cleaner than manipulating VNC inside X?

Comment: barrycarter, of course you can implement your own VNC client.